# Is partial 3D convolution or transpose+2D convolution faster?

Tags: pytorch

I have some data of shape `B*C*T*H*W`. I want to apply 2d convolutions on the `H*W` dimension.

There are two options (that I see):

1. Apply partial 3D convolution with shape (1, 3, 3). 3D convolution accepts data with shape `B*C*T*H*W` which is exactly what I have. This is however a pseudo 3d conv that might be under-optimized (despite its heavy use in P3D networks).
2. Transpose the data, apply 2D convolutions, and transpose the result back. This requires the overhead of data reshaping, but it makes use of the heavily optimized 2D convolutions.

```py
data = raw_data.transpose(1,2).reshape(b*t, c, h, w).detach()
out = conv2d(data)
out = out.view(b, t, c, h, w).transpose(1, 2).contiguous()
```

Which one is faster?

(Note: I have a self-answer below. This aims to be a quick note for people who are googling, aka me 20 minutes ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment: PyTorch 1.7.1, CUDA 11.0, RTX 2080 TI.

TL;DR: Transpose + 2D conv is faster (in this environment, and for the tested data shapes).

Code (modified from [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/conv3d-vs-conv2d-speed/18132)):

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import time

b = 4
c = 64
t = 4
h = 256
w = 256
raw_data = torch.randn(b, c, t, h, w).cuda()

def time2D():
        conv2d = nn.Conv2d(c, c, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda()
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        start = time.time()
        for _ in range(100):
            data = raw_data.transpose(1,2).reshape(b*t, c, h, w).detach()
            out = conv2d(data)
            out = out.view(b, t, c, h, w).transpose(1, 2).contiguous()
            out.mean().backward()
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        end = time.time()
        print("  --- %s ---  " %(end - start))

def time3D():
        conv3d = nn.Conv3d(c, c, kernel_size=(1,3,3), padding=(0,1,1)).cuda()
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        start = time.time()
        for _ in range(100):
            out = conv3d(raw_data.detach())
            out.mean().backward()
        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        end = time.time()
        print("  --- %s ---  " %(end - start))

print("Initializing cuda state")
time2D()

print("going to time2D")
time2D()
print("going to time3D")
time3D()
```

For shape = `4*64*4*256*256`:

```
2D: 1.8675172328948975
3D: 4.384545087814331
```

For shape = `8*512*16*64*64`:

```
2D: 37.95961904525757
3D: 49.730860471725464
```

For shape = `4*128*128*16*16`:

```
2D: 0.6455907821655273
3D: 1.8380646705627441
```